# Laravel Query builder replacing ' into &#039

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have laravel query builder query where is in the where condition I have an ',

```
Select * from teams where name ilike ST. HELLEN'S
```

But when I run this query through Laravel query builder it is converted into

```
Select * from teams where name ilike ST. HELLEN&#039;S
```

And at the end I am getting  Syntax error. Anyone has any idea how to get through this issue?

I have alreadyt tried these

```
Select * from teams where name ilike ST. HELLEN\'S
Select * from teams where name ilike `ST. HELLEN'S`
```

---

This is the code I have:

```
$query = "Select * from teams where name ilike ST. HELLEN\'S"; 
$data = DB::select($query);
```

Also tried:

```
DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

Comment: plz post the laravel's query builder code.

Comment: I am doing it like these..
`
$query = "Select * from teams where name ilike ST. HELLEN\'S";


$data = DB::select($query);
Also tried DB::select(DB::raw($query));

`

Comment: I'm confused about the `ilike` statement. `like` is clear and I use it often, but what is the difference between `like` and `ilike`? I can't find any reference in the MySQL documentation or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: Well like is case sensitive, ilike is not. Also ilike is available only in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to achieve the same

**Way1:** Use another single quote:`'ST. HELLEN''S'`

**Way2:** Use the escape character `\` before the single quote`'`: `'ST. HELLEN\'S'`

**Way3:** Use double quotes to enclose string instead of single quotes: `"ST. HELLEN'S"`